# Application.Inputbox if then statement results mismatch when cancelled

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to automate repetitive tasks by using .inputboxes in Excel.

Note: `CopyAmt` is an integer returned from another `InputBox`, `userInputRange` is type 8 box, and `RowCnt` is the `Row.Count` of `userInputRange`.

```vb
For i = 1 To CopyAmt
    userInputRange.Copy
    ActiveCell.Offset(RowCnt, 0).Activate
    ActiveCell.PasteSpecial
    ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveCell.Offset(, 24), ActiveCell.Offset(RowCnt - 1, 24)).Value = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Internal Value",  Type:=2)
Next i
```

If a user was to click Cancel, I would want to exit the sub only after deleting the selection that was just pasted on line 4 of the above code. This is what I was trying.

```vb
For i = 1 To CopyAmt
    userInputRange.Copy
    ActiveCell.Offset(RowCnt, 0).Activate
    ActiveCell.PasteSpecial
    ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveCell.Offset(, 24), ActiveCell.Offset(RowCnt - 1, 24)).Value = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Internal Value",  Type:=2)
    If ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveCell.Offset(, 24), ActiveCell.Offset(RowCnt - 1, 24)).Value = False Then
        Selection.Delete
        Exit Sub
    End If
Next i
```

This results in a mistype and I would love some clarification on the things I am doing wrong, or just not efficiently.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: There is certainly a lot of [inefficient things](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251/11683) here, but what is the error and on which line?

Comment: Thanks for the reference link. Lots of good advice in there. The error occurs on line 6, the IF statement. When the if statement is present, I am unable to enter anything in the inputbox without getting the Type Error. However, the IF statement does work - if you click cancel the sub ends without error. It seems like the wording of the returned value in the If statement is changing the expected Type in the inputbox.

Comment: On line 6 you refer to the `.Value` of a multicell range. `.Value` of a multicell range is a 2D array (as opposed to the `.Value` of a single cell range, which is a single value). You cannot compare a 2D array to a single value such as `False`. An attempt to do so results in a type mismatch error.

Answer (score 0):

Sean,

Give this a try. Note: this is untested code but should work.

```
For i = 1 To CopyAmt

  userInputRange.Copy
  ActiveCell.Offset(RowCnt, 0).Activate '*** Changes ActiveCell!
  With ActiveCell                       '*** Use With block to simplify code
    .PasteSpecial
    Temp = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Internal Value")
    If (Temp <> False) Then
      ActiveSheet.Range(.Offset(, 24), .Offset(RowCnt - 1, 24)).Value = Temp
    Else
      .ClearContents '*** You don't want to delete the cell just clear the value.
      Return         '*** Get me out of the Subroutine
    End If
    
  End With
  
Next i
```

Edited: Removed the Type=2 from the Application.InputBox line.
You can test for the type of data your need in the latter code.

Comment: Hi RG, Thank you for the response. The ( x <> False) does not allow me to enter a string into the inputbox. I get a mistype again.

Comment: Sean, I edited the response.

Comment: Hi RG, stll getting the type mismatch...not sure why this doesnt work. Thanks for your time.